# SSIS package xml destination

Tags: xml, ssis

I have an SSIS package to get some sort of data from database and put it into an xml file destination. It is working under a foreach loop. While each loop is executing, the data is updated in the destination file. Currently the data is overwriting at each loop. Really I want to append the data.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Assuming your XML looks like `<Outer><Inner>...</Inner></Outer>` would it make sense to have N Outer tags `<Outer><Inner>...</Inner></Outer><Outer><Inner>...</Inner></Outer>` or will the consumer expect something like 1 Outer tag and N Inner tags?

Comment: 1 outer tag and N inner tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrap your XML in a VARCHAR(MAX) and output to a Flat File Destination as per:
http://schottsql.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/ssis-and-xml-output.html

Then edit your Flat File Destination and uncheck the "Overwrite data in the file" option.  Each loop will append to the Flat file.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data to a RecordSet destination and use a Script Component to write the RecordSet to an XML file. The following link contains a step-by-step guide for this process:

- [Yet another SSIS XML Destination](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/yet-another-ssis-xml-destination)