# SSIS- MEMORY Error while creating a large xml file

Tags: sql-server, xml, memory, ssis

I am trying to generate an XML file using SSIS and I get this error:

> [OLE DB Source [19]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE
>   DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Memory allocation failure".

It generates a output when I run it on a subset of data.

The expected row count is to be around 7 million records. It was also working for 7 million records when there were around 9 columns. Recently I added 2 more columns and this error shows up.

What would be the optimal buffer settings to resolve this error?

Thank you

Comment: SSIS went from 2005 up to 2019 with many releases without XML Destination Adapter. I would suggest to use SSIS Execute Process Task based on bcp.exe utility.

Comment: Check the following pos, it contains two methods to generate XML using SSIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865441/ssis-package-xml-destination/56370480#56370480